# Sync a folder on a remote UNIX server from Windows with rsync

Tags: windows, unix, rsync, file-transfer

I am trying to sync the contents of a directory on my Windos machine with a UNIX server.

I have spent a long while reading the rsync documentation and have come up with the following command:

```
rsync --progress -avzC --stats --force --dry-run -e 'ssh -p 176' root@mydomain.com:/home/mydirectory
```

I try to run this from the directory which I wish to sync from but the command fails.

Is the problem that I need to specify the directory I am syncing from?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you need to at least have

```
rsync <source dir> <destination dir>
```

or in your case

```
rsync --progress -avzC --stats --force --dry-run -e 'ssh -p 176' <source dir> <destination dir>
```

You can replace the current directory with:

```
./
```

Comment: ./ was the thing I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't post the error message you're getting, but I think you answered your own question. Rsync requires that you specify both the source and destination paths.